# c++ chrono giving negative epoch time

Tags: c++, time, epoch

I'm using this code to get the current time in milliseconds since epoch

```
std::chrono::milliseconds ms = std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch()
    );
long currTime = (long)ms.count();
```

The problem is i'm getting a negative number now, and each call to this gives me a negative number closer to 0. It has been working fine for weeks and was working a couple hours ago. I don't think i've done anything that should have affected it, but its possible.

Heres a couple example numbers i'm getting:

```
First time: -2145295742
Second time: -2145279907
Third time: -2145268209
Last time: -2144900213
```

my computers clock time is the right date, so why might i be getting negative numbers here?

Comment: Works for me; `std::cout << ms.count();` give positive results. How do you display the duration? It looks like some kind of overflow, although the standard guarantees at leas 45 bits for the integer type http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration

Comment: You haven't shown the part of the code where you convert it and lose data. 1428079769000 is a big number. More than 2³², in fact.

Comment: I'm debugging to see what the result is. all of a sudden my program started mis-behaving. Its been working fine for me the last couple weeks like i said, and even a couple hours ago. now it won't work in debug or release. i've put the release on another machine (which is where i noticed there was a problem) and its doing the same thing there

Comment: @chris there are 45 bits at least for miliseconds, so probably the compiler is using a 64 bit type.

Comment: @vsoftco, Yes, it's fine when it comes out of the library for sure.

Comment: just updated, i'm converting to long. think i should be using long long? i've been using long for weeks and its been working fine, but i did notice there was an issue with the dates being off by a couple years. i'll try using long long

Comment: chris, make that as an answer and i'll mark it correct. i should have been using long long

Comment: @iedoc try `sizeof(long)` and see if its only 32 bits. Why `long` though? Why not `auto currTime = ms.count();`?

Comment: i could have used auto, but i like to use strict types. its a 32 bit application, but i thouglht long was the same as _int64. must be missing something...

Comment: @iedoc, vsoftco really was first.

Comment: either one, thanks guys

Comment: by the way, i was wrong, long is only 32 bits, just tried sizeof. i have no idea how i didn't see that before

Comment: I had this problem on Ubunut, but the same code did not have a problem on mac. I ended up changing the data type to `long long`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overflowing the `long` in your code:

```
long currTime = (long)ms.count();
```

The best thing to do is to make sure your data type is large enough (has enough bits) to represent the duration. I'd do

```
auto currTime = ms.count();
```

Or, make sure you use a type of at least 45 bits (as this is guaranteed to be the [minimum size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) for the integer type in `milliseconds`). I find the `auto` in this case really useful, as your code will be portable, and the right type always used by `currTime`, regardless of compiler/platform.